# How to properly use "Element.style.color"?

Tags: javascript, html, element, dom-manipulation

I'm unsure as to why the text that appears after clicking the "Try it" button isn't red?

HTML:

```
<button onClick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(){
"use strict";
var newpara = document.createElement("p");
var newcontent = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");

// [ADD] Ensure that content is added to the paragraph element
newpara.appendChild(newcontent);

// [ADD] Ensure the paragraph element is added to the document
document.body.appendChild(newpara); 

    Element.style.color="#ff3300";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
`newpara.style.color = '#ff3300'`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

correct `Element` to  `newpara`

```
newpara.style.color="#ff3300";
```

```js
function myFunction(){
"use strict";
var newpara = document.createElement("p");
var newcontent = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");

// [ADD] Ensure that content is added to the paragraph element
newpara.appendChild(newcontent);

// [ADD] Ensure the paragraph element is added to the document
document.body.appendChild(newpara); 

    newpara.style.color="#ff3300";
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `newpara.style.color`.Also you need to append the `newcontent` inside `newpara`

```js
function myFunction() {
  "use strict";
  var newpara = document.createElement("p");
  newpara.style.color = "#ff3300";
  var newcontent = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
  newpara.appendChild(newcontent)
  document.body.appendChild(newpara);

}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```